# Rebuild all Interfaces based on directory of Implementations

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I like using Resharper.   They have a feature for extracting an interface from an implementation.  My solution layout is such that I have one directory for implementation, and one directory for interfaces.  What I would like to be able to do is point to my implementation directory,   then point to my interface directory and have it rebuild all interfaces.   Do you know of any tools or T4 templates to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper has no such functionality built in, and I don't even understand how can one use T4, which is a *templating engine* for this task. ReSharper is pretty extensible, so you can write custom plugin to do that.